# Is this inversion? “Seldom is the weather more dramatic...”

Tags: inversion

> Seldom is the weather more dramatic than when thunderstorms strike.

Is it an inverted sentence?
Or what is it?

Answer (score 3):

> *Seldom is the weather more dramatic than when thunderstorms strike.*

Your example has subject-auxiliary inversion. This occurs in declarative clauses only when certain types of element are put in front position.

Negatives are one very obvious type of element that trigger subject-auxiliary inversion when fronted.

*Never had I seen such chaos*. /   *At no stage were they in danger.*

"Seldom" is classified as an 'approximate negator', hence the inversion. Compare the basic ordering, without fronting:

*The weather is seldom more dramatic than when thunderstorms strike*.

Answer (score 2):

An inverted sentence switches the placement of the verb before the subject of a sentence as if in a question (ie "*Is the weather more dramatic than when thunderstorms strike?*")

So yes, it is inverted. It could also be written as:

> The weather is seldom more dramatic than when thunderstorms strike.